# CORS errors when deploying signalR notification Hub to IIS

Tags: deployment, iis-7, signalr, signalr-hub

My signalR Hub can run fine in VS2019 debug mode on secure port 44311, but as soon as I publish it to my local IIS on my dev box, the `../hub/negotiate` fails with a `CORS policy` exception.

**ex.** in debug mode, the IIS tray

[image]

**and signalr Hub starts fine:**

[image]

---

Now onto my local Window 10 IIS settings where I deployed the signalR Hub project:

1. I setup the https bindings
2. I successfully setup the SSL Cert, and set the Require SSL checkbox:
3. I Restart my IIS Website, and Browse on 44311 to test

[image]

[image]

[image]

But sure enough, my app cannot connect to the HUB:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44311/hub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:`

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

`POST https://localhost:44311/hub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 net::ERR_FAILED`

---

Yet in my code I injected `CORS`:

```js
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using NotificationHub.Hubs;
namespace NotificationHub
{
    public class Startup
    {
        readonly string MyAllowedSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowedSpecificOrigins";

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowedSpecificOrigins,
                                  builder => {
                                      builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200", "localhost:4200")
                                        .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                                        .AllowCredentials()
                                        .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true);
                                  }
                                  );
            });
           
            services.AddSignalR(hubOptions => {
                hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1000);
            });            
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors(MyAllowedSpecificOrigins);

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            // app.UseSession();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {           
                endpoints.MapHub<Notifications>("/hub", options => {
                    options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets | HttpTransportType.LongPolling;
                });
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Notification HUB has started!");                    
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure at this point if it's a coding issue (i.e. not setting CORS properly), or a deployment issue.

Help is appreciated.

thanks.

**UPDATE**

As per the suggested answer below, my CORS issue is resolved when deployed to IIS:

1. Install cors for IIS: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module
2. Add below `<customHeaders>` to web.config

However, I still CANNOT connect to the hub successfully in IIS deployment mode (`http://localhost:55271/hub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 throws 404 not found`); however debug works fine.

```html
<httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Request-Headers" value="User-Agent,Content-Type,Authorization,X-RequestDigest,X-ClientService-ClientTag,XMLHttpRequest,x-requested-with" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="User-Agent,Content-Type,Authorization,X-RequestDigest,X-ClientService-ClientTag,XMLHttpRequest,x-requested-with" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Request-Method" value="GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
```

Comment: Is your issue solved?

If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

If your issue still exists then try to refer the solution given by the community members.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal - you're right. But what happened was that I broke my entire dev solution after trying to deploy it with ssl and a digi cert. Then the 4th of July holiday came, and I finally just rebuilt my dev environment. I will have to revisit this issue ASAP on the local deployment side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you enabled iis .net feature. enable directory browsing in iis for the site:

1)Start IIS Manager.

2)In IIS Manager, expand the server name, expand Web sites, and then select the website.

3)In the Features view, double-click Directory Browsing.

4)In the Actions pane, click Enable.

add below code in web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://my-external-app-domain.com" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Request-Headers" value="User-Agent,Content-Type,Authorization,X-RequestDigest,X-ClientService-ClientTag" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Request-Method" value="GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

install cors module in iis by using web platform installer or from below link:

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module

Update:

Add below  to web.config:

HttpRequest,x-requested-with were both needed in "Access-Control-Request-Headers" . In addition, I inserted header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" with same values as Request-Headers.

Comment: To solve the CORS error I modified the web.config CustomHeaders section. HttpRequest,x-requested-with were both needed in `"Access-Control-Request-Headers"` .  
In addition, I inserted header `name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers"` with same values as Request-Headers.

Comment: fyi: I already installed the CORS module as suggested. That was my first step before adding headers to my web.confg.

Comment: At this point my cors issue is resolved, thank you. Now I'm facing the issue where my front end `http://localhost:55271/hub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1` throws `404 not found` when the IIS hub website running. If I run in vs2019 debug mode (and shut down the hub site in IIS), I have no issues connecting to the hub. Separate so post, perhaps?

Comment: Jalpa - plesae see my Update section in post. The web.config values there worked for me. Please update your answer accordingly; and thank you once again for your help.

Comment: @bob.mazzo sure i will update my post.and for this new issue you could generate new post.